How to change the type of a polymorphic record using lenses?
In the following code snippet, how do I write the toRecordWrite function such that it can work with any DbRecord with similar type-level mechanics, eg. UserPoly id createdAt updatedAt email username or PostPoly id createdAt updatedAt title body
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Try2 where

import Control.Lens
import Data.Time
import Prelude hiding (id)

data DbRecordPoly id createdAt updatedAt name = DbRecordPoly
  { _dbrId        :: id
  , _dbrCreatedAt :: createdAt
  , _dbrUpdatedAt :: updatedAt
  , _dbrName      :: name
  }
$(makeLensesWith abbreviatedFields ''DbRecord)

type DbRecordRead = DbRecordPoly Int UTCTime UTCTime String
type DbRecordWrite = DbRecordPoly () () () String

-- The function definition given below doesn't compile, but I hope
-- it communicates the intent of what I'm trying to achieve
toRecordWrite :: (HasId a Int, HasCreatedAt a UTCTime, HasCreatedAt b UTCTime, HasId b () HasCreatedAt b (), HasUpdatedAt b ()) => a -> b
toRecordWrite a =
  a & id .~ () & createdAt .~ () & updatedAt .~ ()


The problem is that "The type t has fields named a, b, and c" is not the same thing as "All you need to make a value of type t is values for the a, b, and c fields". There may be some other d field you don't know about. It's enough to change a value of type t to some other value of the same type, but not to construct a new one.
This means that your type signature can't merely demand that the return type b satisfies these Has___ classes, because you can't construct a new value of any type given just those constraints. You need to demand something more specific. The most obvious solution is to be extremely specific: operate on DbRecordPoly only.
toRecordWrite :: DbRecordPoly id createdAt updatedAt String -> DbRecordWrite
toRecordWrite = DbRecordPoly () () () . view name

This works fine for your examples with RecordRead and RecordWrite, but doesn't help you with types that have different field sets. It's not 100% clear what you hope might happen if you called toRecordWrite on a value of a type with different fields. Given your examples of UserPoly and PostPoly all feature the same three first fields (id, createdAt, and updatedAt), I can guess that perhaps you intend all of your records to have this same 3-tuple in their header, and you want toRecordWrite to replace the values of these fields with () while leaving the rest of the record alone. The best advice I have for that involves much simpler tools. You don't need any lens stuff, just encode that constraint of "everything has this 3-field header" in the types.
data Headered header payload = Headered header payload
data CommonHeader = CommonHeader {id :: Int, created, updated :: UTCTime}

data DbRecordPayload = DbRecordPayload {dbrName :: String}
type DbRecordPoly h = Headered h DbRecordPayload
type DbRecordRead = DbRecordPoly CommonHeader
type DbRecordWrite = DbRecordPoly ()

data UserPayload = UserPayload {email, username :: String}
type UserPoly h = Headered h UserPayload
type UserRead = UserPoly CommonHeader
type UserWrite = UserPoly ()

With these definitions, you can easily define toWrite such that it converts DbRecordRead to DbRecordWrite, and likewise UserRead to UserWrite:
toWrite :: Headered h p -> Headered () p
toWrite (Headered _ p) = Headered () p


All my records have the same "meta" fields (which you are calling "header" fields). These are fields that are generated by the DB and not by the Haskell code. The approach presented in the solution is similar to what persistent library does. It separates out entityId and entityVal. I was hoping to come up with a different solution :-)

@SaurabhNanda I suggest you clarify what you're hoping to achieve with an alternative solution. If this solution is what I came up with and also what a (presumably well-thought-out) database library does, it's probably a good general-case solution. Only by saying what's lacking about the general solution for your general case can you hope to get a more suitable solution.

Despite the fun I had with my answer, I would probably be more inclined to use the structure amalloy suggests here, where the payload and "header" are in separate types. These header fields aren't "really" part of your core data, they're make sense only in context of the having data in your DB (e.g. setting an id in Haskell is meaningless if you don't actually have this record stored in a DB table under that id). I find I get a fair bit of use out of being able to separate that; I think the desire to stuff them all in a flat record is an artefact of SQL's lack of rich structured types.

The problem is that your function's type has nothing to link the types a and b.
Your constrains say that a has fields id :: Int, createdAt :: UTCTime, and updatedAt :: UTCTime, and that b has fields with those same names all of type (). But there's nothing to say that changing the types of those fields in a to () results in type b; remember the caller can instantiate a and b to any types that meet those constraints. If all your DB types have those 3 fields, then you're effectively promising that you can turn a DB record for a blog post into a DB record for a medical degree simply by changing the id and timestamp fields, if a caller chose to instantiate the types that way! Obviously the type system is right to stop you from writing such a function.
The fundamental issue is not with lenses, but with the generated Has* classes. These give you access to simplified lenses that aren't capable of polymorphic update, precisely because they don't have enough type parameters to connect the types pre- and post- update.
The normal shape of a lens type is Lens s t a b. For the purpose of using them as setters, the idea is that if you can provide an a -> b function the lens can construct an s -> t function; changing the inner field type from a to b will change the outer structure type from s to t. The Has* classes only give you lenses that look like Lens' s a, which merely says that if you give it an a -> a function the lens can construct an s -> s function. When you're using a 2-parameter Lens' rather than a 4-parameter Lens, there's simply no "room" in the types to specify what the relationship is between the starting and final type when you want to change the type of a field (which simply means that you can't use a Lens' to apply updates that change the type of a field, full stop).
For example, if I change your example to use makeLensesWith lensRules instead of abbreviatedFields, then you get no HasId class with overloaded id Lens', you get dbrId as a full type-changing Lens but specifically for DbRecordPoly (and some for the other fields). That would then allow you to write something horrible like this:
toRecordWrite :: (Lens s s1 Int ()) -> (Lens s1 s2 UTCTime ()) -> (Lens s2 t UTCTime ()) -> s -> t
toRecordWrite id createdAt updatedAt record =
  record & id .~ ()
         & createdAt .~ ()
         & updatedAt .~ ()

Here instead of using constraints to get access to the lenses you require them to be passed in explicitly. Now you've got somewhere to write down that your series of 3 updates transforms  the type from s to s1 to s2 and finally to t, specifying the relationship between the input and output type (or at least specifying that the lenses will specify the relationship). We need the types to actually build a "chain" from the input to the output type, not just state some independent facts about the input and output type. Then you can do this in GHCi:
λ :t toRecordWrite dbrId dbrCreatedAt dbrUpdatedAt
toRecordWrite dbrId dbrCreatedAt dbrUpdatedAt
  :: DbRecordPoly Int UTCTime UTCTime name
     -> DbRecordPoly () () () name

And you can see that the compiler can even infer the types involved here (including all the intermediate ones where you've only replaced some of the DbRecordPoly parameters with ()). You could then use this with any type for which you can supply suitable lenses.
Now I'm not suggesting that you actually use this code directly; I'm sure your whole point was for toRecordWrite to contain the logic of which fields it is writing, which it doesn't really do if you have to pass in lenses for the specific fields every time you use it. But it shows you what you need from a solution; not just the knowledge that your type has these 3 fields, but specifically the way your type changes as you change the type of these 3 fields. That requires more complex classes than lens will generate for you.
I tried knocking something up (and somewhat to my surprise!) found a pattern that looks like it works acceptably:
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Time
import Prelude hiding (id)

data DbRecordPoly id createdAt updatedAt name = DbRecordPoly
  { _dbrId        :: id
  , _dbrCreatedAt :: createdAt
  , _dbrUpdatedAt :: updatedAt
  , _dbrName      :: name
  }
  deriving (Show)
$(makeLensesWith lensRules ''DbRecordPoly)

class HasIdLens s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  id :: Lens s t a b

instance HasIdLens (DbRecordPoly id createdAt updatedAt name)
                   (DbRecordPoly id' createdAt updatedAt name)
                   id id'
  where
    id = dbrId

class HasCreatedAtLens s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  createdAt :: Lens s t a b

instance HasCreatedAtLens (DbRecordPoly id createdAt updatedAt name)
                          (DbRecordPoly id createdAt' updatedAt name)
                          createdAt createdAt'
  where
    createdAt = dbrCreatedAt


class HasUpdatedAtLens s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  updatedAt :: Lens s t a b

instance HasUpdatedAtLens (DbRecordPoly id createdAt updatedAt name)
                          (DbRecordPoly id createdAt updatedAt' name)
                          updatedAt updatedAt'
  where
    updatedAt = dbrUpdatedAt


type DbRecordRead = DbRecordPoly Int UTCTime UTCTime String
type DbRecordWrite = DbRecordPoly () () () String


-- NOTE: the functional dependencies on the classes above are very
-- important, so that GHC can use them to generate the chain of
-- intermediate types s1 and s2. Otherwise these would be independent
-- type parameters that need to be correctly specified by the caller
-- every time (using TypeApplications or proxies), making the
-- interface pretty horrible.
toRecordWrite
  :: ( HasIdLens s s1 Int ()
     , HasCreatedAtLens s1 s2 UTCTime ()
     , HasUpdatedAtLens s2 t UTCTime ()
     ) => s -> t
toRecordWrite record =
  record & id .~ ()
         & createdAt .~ ()
         & updatedAt .~ ()

ts :: UTCTime
ts = read "2000-01-01 00:00:00"

dbr = DbRecordPoly (7 :: Int) ts ts "foo"


With that, I can do this in GHCi (note that I added deriving (Show) so you can see this):
λ dbr
DbRecordPoly {_dbrId = 7, _dbrCreatedAt = 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, _dbrUpdatedAt = 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, _dbrName = "foo"}
it :: DbRecordPoly Int UTCTime UTCTime String

λ toRecordWrite dbr
DbRecordPoly {_dbrId = (), _dbrCreatedAt = (), _dbrUpdatedAt = (), _dbrName = "foo"}
it :: DbRecordPoly () () () [Char]

Unfortunately the Has*Lens classes (which you only have to write once) are less annoying to write than than the instances (which you have to write for every type). You could probably get away with a simpler scheme if the type parameters for the fields were at a "known place" in the type (i.e. you always work with types of the form f id createdAt updatedAt), but that would be much less flexible.
This looks mechanical enough that some template haskell ought to be able to generate it, but I couldn't see any options in Control.Lens.TH that would generate classes for full lenses like this, and I don't know of anything that already exists.
